# ¿Cómo obtener datos de la base de datos de Postgres con EntityFramework6.Npgsql en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy creando una aplicación de inicio de sesión en ASP.NET MVC usando Npgsql y EntityFramework6.Npgsql, quiero implementar una función para recuperar la contraseña a través de un número de identificación, es decir, el usuario hace clic en el botón "Olvidé mi contraseña", luego Debe ingresar el número de identificación y el programa verifica si existe o es correcto, luego de eso, se muestra la información del usuario para cambiar la contraseña.

La clase de modelo para el usuario:

```
public partial class user
{

public int id { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Id number")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "It's necessary the id number")]
public string idnumber { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Name")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "It's necessary the name")]
public string fname { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Last name")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "It's necessary the last name)]
public string lname { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Password")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "It's necessary a pass")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Min six letters")]
public string pass { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Confirm pass")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("pass", ErrorMessage = "The pass don't match")]
public string check_pass { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Email")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "It's necessary an email")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Entonces, en [HttpGet] el número de identificación es obtenido por el programa y en [HttpPost] la información es cambiada por el número de identificación, o eso se supone que debe hacer.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult recoverPass()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult recoverPass(userPassRecover user)
{    
    using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {
        var u = dc.user.Where(a => a.cedula == user.cedula).FirstOrDefault();

        dc.user.Remove(u);
        dc.user.Add(user);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Realmente no sé cómo hacer que esto funcione, se agradece cualquier sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el problema es que no recibe los datos: el método GET precisamente no recibe ninguna información. Agregar un nuevo método POST y establecerle un parámetro de tipo string (si este es el tipo de dato del id) puede ayudarte. *Esto si ambas acciones (enviar el número de identificación y cambiar la contraseña) están en la misma vista*.

Si el número de identificación es un string, puedes declarar el nuevo método POST con un parámetro que reciba un string, luego buscar la información del usuario, y retornarla a la vista:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult recoverPass()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostUser(string id)
{
    using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {
       var u = dc.user.Where(a => a.idnumber == id)?.FirstOrDefault();
       if(u != null) return View(u);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Luego, para cambiar la contraseña, simplemente utiliza otro método POST que reciba al usuario y la nueva contraseña para realizarlo.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(user usuario, string nuevaContraseña)
{    
    using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {
        var u = dc.user.Where(a => a.idnumber == usuario.idnumber)?.FirstOrDefault();
        
        if(u != null){
           u.pass = nuevaContraseña;
           dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Nota: es posible que tengas que realizar algunos cambios a las propiedades de los objetos, pues solo me baso en la información que has provisto. Además, recuerda tomar en cuenta los nombres de los métodos a la hora de hacer el POST.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo que hice fue crear un nuevo modelo únicamente con el número de id y la nueva contraseña, es decir con el campo requerido y el campo a cambiar. En la misma Vista se realiza la acción de verificar y la de actualizar la contraseña, seguí la guía que me brindó, pero me tira un error: "El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo...", será que tiene que ver con la Vista? De nuevo, cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: ¿Puedes darme más detalles del error que te presenta? ¿Qué tipo de datos esperas en la vista?

Comment: Este es el error: "El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo … pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo", en los puntos suspensivos muestra un código largo que no sé a que se refiere. En la vista hay dos cuadros de texto, uno para el número de id y el otro para la nueva contraseña, se verifica el número y se actualiza la contraseña, es decir que en la Vista habrían dos datos, el número  de id y la contraseña.

Comment: Precisamente necesitaría saber lo que dice después de "es de tipo...", pues indica el tipo de datos que está esperando. Pero, por lo que veo es simplemente que el modelo que estás pasando a la vista desde el controlador no coincide con el que espera la vista.

Comment: Mira este sería el error completo: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.user_135CDF6ACA46C9824CBD83F883CD16A164B75D102A6942C52231B1CCFCC18DA2', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'regMVC.Models.userRecoverPass'. Ya intenté ajustarlo con lo que tengo, pero no surgue ningún cambio. Gracias por sus respuestas y espero no estar abusando de su tiempo por algo que se ve que es simple.

Comment: Aquí está el problema: la clase que pasas a la vista es `user`, y la que espera la vista es `userRecoverPass`. Dado que no son lo mismo, no se trata solo de ajustar los modelos para que se parezcan, es que tiene que ser la misma clase (que es lo que el modelo representa). Así que, entre otras cosas, tienes dos opciones: cambia el modelo que esperas en la vista por el de `user`, o cambia el modelo que envías a la vista desde el controlador por el de `userRecoverPass`. En esta última recuerda pasarle los datos que necesita el modelo para que no llegue vacío a la vista. Quedo a la orden.

Comment: Solucionado, han sido muy útiles sus aportes, al final cambié el modelo a userRecoverPass y ya pude hacer la actualización.